# Why is my NVEnc image coming out pixelated?

Tags: c++, h.264, nvenc

I have been working on an NVEnc project but the images seem to come out blurry no matter what I do in the setup if I am using CBR as my rate control mode. I am adapting the code from the NVidia sample here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/video-sdk-samples/blob/master/nvEncBroadcastSample/nvEnc/nvCodec/nvEncoder/NvEncoder.cpp

I am using CBR as my rate control mode as suggested in this table from the nvidia docs.

[image: nvidia reccomendation]

```
m_encoder->SetEncoderParams(&m_encInitParams, m_codecId, NV_ENC_PRESET_LOW_LATENCY_HQ_GUID);

[...]

void NvEncoder::SetEncoderParams(NV_ENC_INITIALIZE_PARAMS* pIntializeParams, GUID codecGuid, GUID presetGuid)
{
    if (!m_encoder)
    {
        NVENC_THROW_ERROR("Encoder Initialization failed", NV_ENC_ERR_NO_ENCODE_DEVICE);
        return;
    }

    if (pIntializeParams == nullptr || pIntializeParams->encodeConfig == nullptr)
    {
        NVENC_THROW_ERROR("pInitializeParams and pInitializeParams->encodeConfig can't be NULL", NV_ENC_ERR_INVALID_PTR);
    }

    memset(pIntializeParams->encodeConfig, 0, sizeof(NV_ENC_CONFIG));
    auto pEncodeConfig = pIntializeParams->encodeConfig;
    memset(pIntializeParams, 0, sizeof(NV_ENC_INITIALIZE_PARAMS));
    pIntializeParams->encodeConfig = pEncodeConfig;


    pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->version = NV_ENC_CONFIG_VER;
    pIntializeParams->version = NV_ENC_INITIALIZE_PARAMS_VER;

    pIntializeParams->encodeGUID = codecGuid;
    pIntializeParams->presetGUID = presetGuid;

    pIntializeParams->encodeWidth = m_width;
    pIntializeParams->encodeHeight = m_height;
    pIntializeParams->darWidth = m_width;
    pIntializeParams->darHeight = m_height;
    pIntializeParams->maxEncodeWidth = m_width;
    pIntializeParams->maxEncodeHeight = m_height;

    pIntializeParams->frameRateNum = 60;
    pIntializeParams->frameRateDen = 1;


    pIntializeParams->enablePTD = 1;
    pIntializeParams->reportSliceOffsets = 1;
    pIntializeParams->enableSubFrameWrite = 0;
    pIntializeParams->enableMEOnlyMode = m_motionEstimationOnly;
    pIntializeParams->enableWeightedPrediction = 1;
#if defined(_WIN32)
    pIntializeParams->enableEncodeAsync = true;
#endif

    NV_ENC_PRESET_CONFIG presetConfig = { NV_ENC_PRESET_CONFIG_VER, { NV_ENC_CONFIG_VER } };
    m_nvenc.nvEncGetEncodePresetConfig(m_encoder, codecGuid, presetGuid, &presetConfig);
    memcpy(pIntializeParams->encodeConfig, &presetConfig.presetCfg, sizeof(NV_ENC_CONFIG));
    pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->frameIntervalP = 1;

    pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->gopLength = NVENC_INFINITE_GOPLENGTH;

    pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->rcParams.rateControlMode = NV_ENC_PARAMS_RC_CBR_LOWDELAY_HQ;
    pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->rcParams.averageBitRate = INT16_MAX;
    //pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->rcParams.maxBitRate = 99999999999;
    pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->rcParams.zeroReorderDelay = 1;

    if (pIntializeParams->encodeGUID == NV_ENC_CODEC_H264_GUID)
    {
        pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->encodeCodecConfig.h264Config.idrPeriod = NVENC_INFINITE_GOPLENGTH; //pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->gopLength;
        pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->encodeCodecConfig.h264Config.sliceMode = 1;
        pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->encodeCodecConfig.h264Config.sliceModeData = INT16_MAX - 50;
        pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->encodeCodecConfig.h264Config.repeatSPSPPS = 1;
    }
    else if (pIntializeParams->encodeGUID == NV_ENC_CODEC_HEVC_GUID)
    {
        pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.pixelBitDepthMinus8 = 0;
        pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->encodeCodecConfig.hevcConfig.idrPeriod = pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->gopLength;
    }
}
```

These settings are generating images that look like this:

[image: sample]

I'd really appreciate any pointers as to why my images are coming out so heavily pixelated when the settings appear to be correct AFAICT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the average bitrate to 32768 (INT16_MAX)

pIntializeParams->encodeConfig->rcParams.averageBitRate = INT16_MAX;

I'd use 5000000 for HD and 20000000 for 4k as average bitrate.

FYI: NV_ENC_RC_PARAMS::averageBitRate is a 32 bit unsigned integer (uint32_t)

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for the answer you're right, I thought I had tried that but I now see that I tried setting max bitrate rather than average, cheers!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project.